# How can i edit the content on my django website pages?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, content-management-system

I'm a newbie to django and i have worked on a few projects and in all of them i used the django admin interface to manage the content, which obviously is the content from my models.My main concern is how or rather is there a way i can edit the content in areas like the about section or on my home page without changing the actual `html` on my code?

Comment: You can choose something like the Django CMS.

Comment: Can django CMS be integrated to use my already built templates?i already have templates with the content hard coded manually.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new model that looks something like this:

```
class HTMLModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    content = models.TextField()
```

Then you can just load the model in your template and print it out:

```
<h1>{{ model.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ model.content }}</p>
```

Now you are able to change the content from the admin interface and it will show the changes on your webpage.

EDIT: On loading the model, I would assume you just create one instance, so you can load it like so:

```
return render(request, 'about_me.html', {
    model: HTMLModel.objects.get(pk=1)
})
```

If you have multiple pages, just add a new field to your model which indicates on which page it should be displayed:

```
class HTMLModel(models.Model):
    page_name = models.CharField()
    title = models.CharField()
    content = models.TextField()
```

Then in your views, you just return the model where page_name = the requested name:

```
model = HTMLModels.objects.get(page_name=request.path)
```

Comment: what if you have lots of pages and fields in your django admin?

Comment: Updated my answer